# javascript - await bootstrap modal close by user

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that shows a message before some other code runs after it.

I want to prevent the code until the user has pressed the OK button on it. I tried `async/await` like this below, which doesn't work, of course.

```
async function myMessage(){
    $('#id_my_modal').modal('show');
}

await myMessage();
```

I know I could use `alert()` but that doesn't work when screen is off while that code is executed. I am making a webRTC video call app. If there is incoming call I show a message which works when user is screen is on. But when screen is off and there is an incoming call `alert()` doesn't appear. Same with media permission dialog. It happens in FF, at least. But a modal appears even when the screen was off. That is why I want a modal.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Finally got it working by using promises.

```
async function myMessage(){
    $('#id_my_message_modal').modal('show');
    return new Promise(resolve => 
        $('#id_my_message_button').on('click', () => {
                $('#id_my_message_modal').modal('hide');
                resolve();
            }
        )
    );
}
```

then

```
await myMessage();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but "await myMessage();" must be set within an async function that call it.  Otherwise you'll get an error saying that " await myMessage() must be set within an asynch function or top module" (I think, on the latter)